# Ubuntu - both wifi and enthernet conection aren't recognized

Tags: networking, 20.04, connection

've got strange problem with ubuntu (20.04.1 LTS 64bit). Ubuntu doesn't recognize any internet connection, in fact it doesnt even recognize wifi and enthernet adapters. (ifconfig -a only shows lo and docker interfaces )

I've tried some solutions found on the internet but nothing works.

I wanted to simply reinstall ubuntu, but unfortunately I've got all files / programs and system on same partition.

Btw I don't know if thats a reason of my problems or just a coincidence, but all problems appeared after I had installed google-chrome.deb

Can I somehow 'reinstall' or 'reset' ubuntu using bootable usb? Or just from OS?

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: Backup your user data from  `/home/` to an external disk before beginning (continuing).    `dpkg  -L google-chrome` to see installed files.